# Problems with priyect CucumberJS, Selenium and Assert Nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, assert, geckodriver, cucumberjs

I hope someone can help me, I have the following code in the class js step_definitions.js:

```
 Then('Validacion de nombre de boton debe ser {string}',function(title) {
    var bton_login="/html/body/app-root/app-login/section/form/div/div[4]/button";
    var val_esperado="Iniciar Sesión";
    this.driver.findElement({xpath: bton_login}).getText().then(function (val_btn) {

      //console.log('valor de elemento boton: ',val_btn);

        assert.equal(val_btn, title)

    });



  });
```

Which when executed in the console shows me the respective validation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqgWo.png)

But as seen in the log it is seen in the successful cases the cucumber execution disappeared and leave the steps all as pass

Comment: You either need to 1) `await` the last statement and make your function `async` or 2) return the last statement; Cucumber will automatically wait for the promise to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

As per the details from 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-assert', we need to use '.then(callback)' on every assertion. Try with this approach and check.

If above approach is not work out, use 'chai' npm library to do this validation like:
expect(actualResult).to.equal(expectedResult, 'Assertion message');